# How to prevent a function from overwriting memory?

Tags: stm32, arm, memory, cmsis

I'm writing a program that basically aquires samples from a signal and does FFT on it (I'm using STM32L432KC MCU). I'm trying to send results from the FFT calculations through UART but there is a problem. I've done some debugging myself and found some information:

The arm_rfft_fast_f32() functions (fft function from cmsis dsp) overwrites important memory that contains UART State data among others.

How can I prevent it?

Images of the problem:

This is one instruction BEFORE memory is overwritten (before FFT function executes), data in red circle is the UART State data (0x20 is UART_READY or whatever)
[image]

This is one instruction AFTER the FFT function executed - look at the memory and see that my UART State got overwritten
[image]

Code:

````
#include "main.h"
#include <arm_math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NS  128
uint32_t Wave_LUT[NS] = {
    2048, 2149, 2250, 2350, 2450, 2549, 2646, 2742, 2837, 2929, 3020, 3108, 3193, 3275, 3355,
    3431, 3504, 3574, 3639, 3701, 3759, 3812, 3861, 3906, 3946, 3982, 4013, 4039, 4060, 4076,
    4087, 4094, 4095, 4091, 4082, 4069, 4050, 4026, 3998, 3965, 3927, 3884, 3837, 3786, 3730,
    3671, 3607, 3539, 3468, 3394, 3316, 3235, 3151, 3064, 2975, 2883, 2790, 2695, 2598, 2500,
    2400, 2300, 2199, 2098, 1997, 1896, 1795, 1695, 1595, 1497, 1400, 1305, 1212, 1120, 1031,
    944, 860, 779, 701, 627, 556, 488, 424, 365, 309, 258, 211, 168, 130, 97,
    69, 45, 26, 13, 4, 0, 1, 8, 19, 35, 56, 82, 113, 149, 189,
    234, 283, 336, 394, 456, 521, 591, 664, 740, 820, 902, 987, 1075, 1166, 1258,
    1353, 1449, 1546, 1645, 1745, 1845, 1946, 2047
}; //sine wave lookup table

ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;

DAC_HandleTypeDef hdac1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_dac_ch1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart2_tx;

int addressState = 0x2000350c;
arm_rfft_fast_instance_f32 fft_handler;
float32_t FFT_buffer_in[2048];
float32_t FFT_buffer_out[1024];
uint32_t analogInput;
uint16_t i = 0;
uint16_t dominatingFreqency = 0;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_DAC1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void doFFT(void);
float complexABS(float real, float imag);
uint8_t findBiggestValue(uint8_t* array, uint16_t size);

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{

}

void HAL_UART_TxHalfCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{

}


void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
    if (i<2048)
    {
        FFT_buffer_in[i] = (3.3*analogInput)/4095;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 0;
    }

}
int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_DAC1_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();

   arm_rfft_fast_init_f32(&fft_handler, 2048);

   HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, &analogInput, 1);
   HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac1, DAC_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t*)Wave_LUT, 128, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
   HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);
   HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim1);

  while (1)
  {
      if(i == 2048)
      {
          doFFT();
      }
      if(dominatingFreqency != 0)
      {
            uint8_t MSG[] = "test ";
            HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart2,MSG, sizeof(MSG));
            dominatingFreqency = 0;
      }
  }

}

float complexABS(float real, float imag)
{
    return sqrtf((real*real+imag*imag));
}

uint8_t findBiggestValue(uint8_t* array, uint16_t size)
{
    uint8_t max = array[1];
    uint16_t max_i;
    for(uint16_t i = 2; i<size; i++)
    {
        if((array[i] > max) && (array[i] < (uint8_t)200))
        {
            max = array[i];
            max_i = i;
        }
    }

    return max_i;
}

void doFFT()
{

    //(pointer to arm_rfft_fast_instance_f32 structure, pointer to input data, pointer to output data, inverse fft =1 or regular fft =0)
    arm_rfft_fast_f32(&fft_handler, FFT_buffer_in, FFT_buffer_out, 0);

        //np. f_sample 45ks/s, 1/45k = 1sample_time = 22.22us, 1024 samples = 1024*22.22u = 0.02275sec in full window (1024 samples)
        //wynik *2 bo zbieramy 2048 probek a przedstawiamy jako 1024? wiec okres okna = 0.0455s, f_okna = 22Hz
        //1bin = 1 okres w tym oknie = 22Hz, 2bin = 44Hz, 10bin = 220Hz, 91bin = 2kHz ... 512bin = 11.25kHz

    uint8_t spectrum[1024];
    uint16_t spectrumPoint = 0;

    //calculate ABS values and do linear to dB conversion:
    for (int i=0; i<2048; i=i+2)
    {
        int to_dB = (int)(20*log10f(complexABS(FFT_buffer_out[i], FFT_buffer_in[i+1])));
        uint8_t to_8bit = (uint8_t)to_dB;
        spectrum[spectrumPoint] = to_8bit;
        if (spectrum[spectrumPoint]<0)
        {
            spectrum[spectrumPoint] = 0;
        }

        spectrumPoint++;

    }

    dominatingFreqency = (findBiggestValue(spectrum, (sizeof(spectrum)))) * 22;
    //uint8_t MSG[30] = {'\0'};
    //sprintf(MSG,"freq: %u", dominatingFreqency);



}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 40;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART2|RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart2ClockSelection = RCC_USART2CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  PeriphClkInit.AdcClockSelection = RCC_ADCCLKSOURCE_PLLSAI1;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1Source = RCC_PLLSOURCE_MSI;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1M = 1;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1N = 32;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1P = RCC_PLLP_DIV7;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1Q = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1R = RCC_PLLR_DIV8;
  PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1ClockOut = RCC_PLLSAI1_ADC1CLK;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */
  /** Common config
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV8;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIG_T1_TRGO;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  hadc1.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_6;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_12CYCLES_5;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief DAC1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_DAC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC1_Init 0 */

  DAC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC1_Init 1 */
  /** DAC Initialization
  */
  hdac1.Instance = DAC1;
  if (HAL_DAC_Init(&hdac1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** DAC channel OUT1 config
  */
  sConfig.DAC_SampleAndHold = DAC_SAMPLEANDHOLD_DISABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_Trigger = DAC_TRIGGER_T2_TRGO;
  sConfig.DAC_OutputBuffer = DAC_OUTPUTBUFFER_ENABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_ConnectOnChipPeripheral = DAC_CHIPCONNECT_DISABLE;
  sConfig.DAC_UserTrimming = DAC_TRIMMING_FACTORY;
  if (HAL_DAC_ConfigChannel(&hdac1, &sConfig, DAC_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DAC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END DAC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 80;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 22;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 625; //freqency of the generated sin (in the case of prescaler = 0):
                          // for example: 1 cycle = 1/f_clock = 1/80MHz = 12.5ns
                          //period = ile zliczamy cykli (ile odliczamy czasu) => period*1cycle = odliczany czas
                          //np. 314*12.5ns = 3925ns (co tyle czasu timer sie przepelnia i dostajemy interrupt ktory generuje probke przez DAC)
                          //zeby wygenerowac 1 okres sinusoidy w naszym przypadku potrzebujemy 128 probek, wiec mamy 3.925us na probke
                          //to 1 okres sin = 128*3.925u = 502.4us,  f_sin = 1/502.4us = 2kHz (zegar sie waha i wgl wiec to idealnie tyle nigdy ni bedzie?)
                          //ostateczny wzor na f_sin (w tym przypadku) = 1/(period*12.5ns*128)
                          //wzor na period dla chcianego f_sin (bo to period zmieniamy): period = 1/(f_sin*12.5ns*128)
                          //########### period = 1/(f_sin*1.6u) ##########
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);
  /* DMA1_Channel3_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel3_IRQn);
  /* DMA1_Channel7_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel7_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel7_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't tell it to overwrite memory.

Read the documentation *carefully*.  The function takes in N real-valued data points, and returns N/2 **complex-valued** data points.  Each complex-valued data point contains **two** real values.  So both input and output vectors need to be *the same size*.

Note that this illustrates something about the FFT: it preserves all the information in the input vector, it just shuffles it around.  You can, in fact, express the discrete Fourier transform (which is just the general form of the *fast* Fourier transform) as a matrix multiply.  So -- if you give it 2048 real numbers going in, then you need 2048 real numbers (where one complex number contains two reals) going out, or information is lost.  Thus, you can reason out from first principles that your output vector is too small.

- `arm_rfft_fast_init_f32(&fft_handler, 2048);` <- 2048-point FFT
- `float32_t FFT_buffer_in[2048];` <- Enough space for 2048 32-bit floats
- `float32_t FFT_buffer_out[1024];` <- Enough space for **only** 1024 32-bit floats, **not** 2048.  Or enough space for **only** 512 complex numbers based on 32-bit floats, **not** 1024.

Comment: Actually, it isn't that information is lost since the function assumes you gave it a large enough output buffer. So the function continues writing output data past the buffer and clobbers whatever is past the buffer.

Comment: Maybe you don't intend all the bold and italics to make it read as shouty and exasperated but it does. You could remove it to improve it, would upvote then. Words emphasise themselves fine on their own. Otherwise well-written.

Comment: +1 for good use of bold and italics to emphasize the important words.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I changed the vector size and it works great now, thank you!